# Setting CFBundleVersion when using xcodebuild

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using xcodebuild

```
xcodebuild -version
Xcode 5.1.1
Build version 5B1008
```

to build my app. In my `App-Info.plist` file I have the `CFBundleVersion` set to `1.1.0`, but after the build, `Info.plist` in the `IPA` file has a value of `1.0`.
I've tried adding the `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION=1.1.0` to `xcodebuild` command, but even though it's listed there in build logs, in the end, the `Info.plist` file has value of `1.0`.
In xcode I can see the value `1.1.0`. When building using xcode it's `1.1.0`, but I have to use `xcodebuild`, since it'a remote build functionality.

Is there anything I'm missing to correctly set the value?

Thanks